# GitLab CI teams notification on specific step

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, continuous-deployment, cicd

I'm try to create a notification when a specific pipeline step is execute.

In particular I have a GitLab pipeline that execute the deploy of the master branch in test environment like the following

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  # script for deploy
  only:
  - master
```

I want to publish to teams channel only when this step is triggered.

Exist a way to do this? I already know the standard integration between GitLab and Teams but this publish a message every time the pipeline run and not only for a specific step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a [webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook) in teams and using `curl` send the data you need in the script section.

```
script:
 - curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"test": "test"}' $WEBHOOK_URL
```